# I get notifications for another user with same user name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, notifications

This question was posted by another user with the same user name as me:
[monospace font not lining up](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30024/105)

I received a notification for a comment addressed to that user.

Can't SE keep straight different users who might have the same name? Don't they have unique IDs internally?

Comment: Were there any other comments at this quesiton you linked?

Comment: The comments I see *are* addressed to you

Comment: But if I am missing something then as stated in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988), comment pings match only names, not user IDs so you can get incorrectly pinged for comments... but that has *nothing* to do with who posted the question, it would only happen because you already *commented*

Comment: Talking to yourself is a sign of madness.  Seek help.

Answer (score 10):

You are the only person other than the author that has commented on the question. Thus, any comments the author posts (which all three were posted by the author, *not* another user trying to notify the author) are assumed to be directed at you and thus you are notified of all three of those comments.